# Estimating Gaussian noise model given a set of linear transformation

Tags: probability, statistics

I've done this stuff in a while.

Suppose we have a system of the form

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\tilde{x}_1 = x_1 + \epsilon_1 \\
\vdots \\
\tilde{x}_i = x_i + \epsilon_i \\
\vdots \\
\tilde{x}_n = x_n + \epsilon_n
\end{array}
\right.
$$

where each $\epsilon_i$ is some value sampled from a distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$

I've these measures $\tilde{x}_i$s not related to the same quantity, but all the $\epsilon_i$ are sampled from the same distribution. Is there any way I can possibly estimate the probability distribution (namely $\mu,\sigma$)?

Thank you

Comment: What do we know about the $x_i$ ? Known distribution ? Fixed values ?

Comment: @Damien, they're fixed/constants.

Comment: In this case, I don't understand where the problem is. By removing the $x_i$ from the observations, you get the $\epsilon_i$. Estimating the mean and variance from these corrected observations seem simple. On the contrary, if they are fixed but unknown (classical case in communications), we need more information on it.

Comment: They're fixed and unknown, except they're constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\epsilon_i\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$, then not enough information about the $x_i$'s is given. If it is a constant deterministic value, you don't need to subscript it. Two cases:

1. The $x_i$'s are all equal and constant (equal to $x$). Then $\widetilde{x}\sim\mathcal{N}(x+\mu,\sigma)$. Let $\mu_x=\mu+x$. Since you can only observe the $\widetilde{x}_i$'s, we can estimate $\mu_x$ (via e.g. $\mu_x\approx(1/n)\sum_i \widetilde{x}_i$), but we have no way to obtain $\mu$ or $x$. That would be like solving $a+b=5$ for $a$ and $b$ with no other knowledge. More information would be needed. However, we can estimate $\sigma$ easily. It's just the usual $\sigma\approx (1/[n-1])\sum_i (x_i - \mu_x)^2$.
2. If the $x_i$'s follow some distribution, e.g. $x_i\sim P(\theta)$, then we have even more trouble. The estimated variances will be affected by $\theta$ as well, i.e. our estimate of $\sigma$ will also include the variance from the random $x_i$.